# Can't access new table column getting error undefined method name app_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I added another table called Application and I referenced the Wikis table in it.  I am trying to add the Application table's column of app_name to the new.html.erb form so the user can add the app name in there when they submit the form.  I am getting "undefined method app_name". How do I  access the column app_name correctly in the index.html.erb file? It appears that wiki.app_name is not the correct way to access app_name in the index.html.erb file?

**Error Message:**

*NoMethodError in Wikis#new*

**new.html.erb file:**

```
<h1>New Bug Defect</h1>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form_for @wiki do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter defect title" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :app_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :app_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Application affected" %>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 33, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Place your defect entry"%>
  </div>


   <div class="form-group">
   <% if current_user.can_make_private_wiki? %>
    <%= f.label :private, class: "checkbox" %>
    <%= f.check_box :private %>
   <% end %>

   </div> 



  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit  "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "applications", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "app_name"
t.string   "dev_resource"
t.integer  "wikis_id"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end

add_index "applications", ["wikis_id"], name: "index_applications_on_wikis_id"


  create_table "wikis", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "title"
   t.text     "body"
   t.boolean  "private",    default: false
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
   end

   add_index "wikis", ["user_id"], name: "index_wikis_on_user_id"
```

**Index.html.erb file showing the app name field**

```
 h1>List of Bug Defects</h1>
<table class="table">
 <tr> 
  <th colspan="0">
  <h2>Defects</h2>
   </th>  
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <th>Title</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>Application</th>
   <th>Link</th>
   <th>Opened by</th>
   </tr>
    <% unless @wikis.nil? %>
    <% @wikis.each do |wiki| %> 
       <tr>
      <td><%= wiki.title %></td>
      <td><%= wiki.body %></td>
      <td><%= wiki.app_name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to wiki.title, wiki_path(wiki)%></td>
      <td><%= wiki.user.name if wiki.user %></td>
      </tr>
         <% end %>
         <% end %>
    </table>
```

**Wiki Controller:**

```
 class WikisController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_wiki, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
   @wikis = policy_scope(Wiki)
  end

  def show
   authorize @wiki
  end

  def new
   @wiki = Wiki.new
   authorize @wiki
  end

  def create
   @wiki = Wiki.new(wiki_params)
   @wiki.user_id = current_user.id
   authorize @wiki

   if @wiki.save
   flash[:notice] = "Your wiki has been saved."
   redirect_to @wiki
   else
   flash[:error] = "Something went wrong."
   render :new
   end
  end

  def edit
   @collaborators = @wiki.collaborators
   @new_collaborator = Collaborator.new
   #authorize @wiki
  end

  def update
   #@wiki.user_id = current_user
   authorize @wiki
    if @wiki.update_attributes(wiki_params)
     flash[:notice] = "Wiki is updated"
     redirect_to @wiki
    else 
     flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the wiki. Please try again."
     render :edit
    end
    end

    def destroy

    if @wiki.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Wiki deleted successfully"
     redirect_to wikis_path
    else
     flash[:error] = "Something went wrong"
    render :show
    end
    end

  private

   def find_wiki
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
   end

   def wiki_params
   params.require(:wiki).permit(:body, :title, :private)
   end
 end
```

Comment: Did you run the migration?

Comment: Yes the table is in the schema I pasted above.

Comment: `:application` is an attribute of `Application` model, not `Wiki`. How is the relation between these models?

Comment: Shoot I forgot to place the reference of the Wiki table in the Application table!  I'll do another db migrate and fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make life easier, I added the column to the existing Wikis table.  It is working correctly now:

```
rails g  migration AddApplicationToWikis application:string
```

**Updated Wikis table:**

```
create_table "wikis", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "body"
t.boolean  "private",     default: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
t.string   "application"
end

add_index "wikis", ["user_id"], name: "index_wikis_on_user_id"
```